# How to customise the login page on roundcube

Tags: html, css, authentication, roundcube

I have installed roundcube on my server, but I wish to make a couple of changes for example, I wish to change username to email and also the browser title. I am using the Larry skin and i am using version 1.3.10

I have checked all file and can't seem to find the correct one, I have checked youtube, the roundcube website and even her, but I can seem to find anything relating to my issue.

When i go to the login.html page, then all i get is the following code:

```
<roundcube:object name="doctype" value="html5" />
<html>
<head>
<title><roundcube:object name="pagetitle" /></title>
<roundcube:include file="/includes/links.html" />
</head>
<body class="login">

<h1 class="voice"><roundcube:object name="productname" /> <roundcube:label name="login" /></h1>

<div id="login-form">
<div class="box-inner" role="main">
<roundcube:object name="logo" src="/images/roundcube_logo.png" id="logo" />

<roundcube:form name="form" method="post">
<roundcube:object name="loginform" form="form" size="40" submit=true />
</form>

</div>

<div class="box-bottom" role="complementary">
    <roundcube:object name="message" id="message" />
    <noscript>
        <p class="noscriptwarning"><roundcube:label name="noscriptwarning" /></p>
    </noscript>
</div>

<div id="bottomline" role="contentinfo">
    <roundcube:object name="productname" /> <roundcube:object name="version" condition="config:display_version" />
    <roundcube:if condition="config:support_url" />
        &nbsp;&#9679;&nbsp; <a href="<roundcube:var name='config:support_url' />" target="_blank" class="support-link"><roundcube:label name="support" /></a>
    <roundcube:endif />
    <roundcube:container name="loginfooter" id="bottomline" />
</div>
</div>

<roundcube:include file="/includes/footer.html" />

<roundcube:object name="preloader" images="
  /images/ajaxloader.gif
  /images/ajaxloader_dark.gif
  /images/buttons.png
  /images/addcontact.png
  /images/filetypes.png
  /images/listicons.png
  /images/messages.png
  /images/messages_dark.png
  /images/quota.png
  /images/selector.png
  /images/splitter.png
  /images/watermark.jpg
" />

</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUcxJ.jpg

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In case your problem is not resolved, please follow steps below

1. Open /roundcubemail/program/localization/en_US file
2. Change following parameter

   ```
   // login page
   $labels['username']  = 'Username';
   ```

   to

   ```
   $labels['username']  = 'Email';
   ```